# Error with enum in named query - the field cannot be resolved to a valid type

Tags: jpa, eclipselink

I've the following error:

```
The state field path 'rel.type' cannot be resolved to a valid type
```

when compiling the named-query inside the following entity:

```java
@NamedQueries({
@NamedQuery(name="findAll" , 
            query="SELECT rel " +
                    "FROM R01EDBEntityForStructureLabelsRelation rel " +
                   "WHERE rel.type = :type")
})
@Entity 
@Table(name = "R01ELABELRELATIONST00") @Cacheable(false)    
@Accessors(prefix="_")
@NoArgsConstructor
public class R01EDBEntityForStructureLabelsRelation {
    @Id @Column(name="SRC_LABEL_OID",length=50) @Basic
    @Getter @Setter private String _sourceLabelOid;

    @Column(name="TYPE",length=10) @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Getter @Setter private R01MStructureLabelRelationType _type;
}
```

The type *R01MStructureLabelRelationType* is a simple enum like:

```java
public enum R01MStructureLabelRelationType {
    SIMILAR
    ALIAS
}
```

any ideas?

Comment: You named your field `_type`, not `type`.

Comment: So simple! I cannot belive I've not seen it before!... I've had this same error some times before and it's related to my own convention of naming private fields with a underscore (yes it's not recomended).
Thank you very much...